# What does 'pull at the nails' mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does 'pull at the nails' mean here for Jesus?

> We learned that when he was up on the cross Jesus didn’t **pull at the
>   nails**.

Flood Show
by Charles Baxter

Comment: Which part of that phrase is confusing?  There's probably no special meaning, here, to *pull at* or *the nails*.

Comment: That's the [carpentry] nails fixing Him to the cross - nothing to do with [*hanging on by His **(finger)nails***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22hung+on+by+his+nails%22).

Comment: the verb - pull at, confuse me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pull at something generally means to take hold of something and repeatedly pull on it. For example:

> He pulled at his ear thoughtfully.

This usage here seems a little unusual to me, but the speaker is presumably saying that Jesus did not try to pull his limbs off of the nails or to pull the nails out of the wood. The implication is that he accepted his death willingly.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that he didn't try to **resist** or **fight against** being up on the cross.